# Optimize Java Regular expression

Tags: java, regex, performance, maintainability

I have a file with huge if statements like this:

```
if ((Pattern.compile("string1|String2|String3").matcher(text_str).find()) 
    && (Pattern.compile("String4|String5").matcher(text_str).find())
    && (Pattern.compile("String6|String7|String8").matcher(text_str).find())
    && (Pattern.compile("String9|String10").matcher(text_str).find())
    && (Pattern.compile("String11|String12").matcher(text_str).find())
    && (Pattern.compile("String13|String14").matcher(text_str).find())
    && (Pattern.compile("String15|String16").matcher(text_str).find())
    && (Pattern.compile("String17|String18").matcher(text_str).find())
    && (Pattern.compile("String19|String19|String20").matcher(text_str).find())
    ) {
    return true;
```

}

I basically need to do checks for a strings like (Pseudocode):

```
String contains? (I have a) AND (cat OR dog OR fish) AND (and it) AND (eats OR drinks OR smells) AND (funny OR a lot OR nothing)
```

how would I make this more maintainable and efficient with a very big amount of checks?

Comment: If your code works, it may be better to go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are string1, string2 ... literal strings?

Comment: So when you say "String1", "String2", etc, these are just placeholders for the real strings, right? And are the actual strings just plain old strings or do they contain any real regexes (e.g., things like `\d`, etc)?

Comment: You match, OK, but what are you doing with these matches?

Comment: The String1 etc. are just plain old words. I want to check if a sentence fullfills certain patterns, like the example in the pseodocode.

Comment: What do you do in case of matching? Are you just checking if the String follows that set of words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with one regex using a series of look-aheads:

```
return text_str.matches("(?s)^(?=.*(string1|String2|String3))(?=.*(String4|String5))(?=.*(String6|String7|String8))(?=.*(String9|String10))(?=.*(String11|String12))(?=.*(String13|String14))(?=.*(String15|String16))(?=.*(String17|String18))(?=.*(String19|String19|String20))");
```

Comment: +1 simplest answer, maybe it would be best to define the words on variables for better visibility and maintainability.

Comment: Yes I thought about that option but I found it to hard to maintain. What I might do is write a function that generates this regexs from a array of words. Would this expression work for a string that has many lines in it, like a html page?

Comment: @aboca yeah I would make a little regex builder method - too great a chance of messing it up. Re multi-line, I have added the "dotall" flag, so "yes, it will work over many lines"

Comment: @Bohemian In order to avoid catastrophic backtracking it might worth it to make the *s lazy.

Comment: @FarhadAliNoo interesting, how would you do that? I haven't experience in that

Comment: @Aboca you make it lazy(as opposed to greedy) by adding a ? after it so `.*?` is lazy. It tries to match the least amount of characters.

Comment: @Aboca: Could you give an example for the above line from Bohemian?

Comment: @FarhadAliNoo There is no possibility of catastrophic backtracking with this regex. Making the quantifier reluctant (or "lazy" as you put it) makes absolutely no difference (and the reason has nothing to do with back tracking)

Comment: @user1759796 Which line? I'm lost. You mean a function to generate the regex?

Comment: @Bohemian I guess I shouldn't have used "catastrophic backtracking". That's a different concept. What I meant was when the string is `aaaaaastring1aaaaaastring1`. You want the first `string1` to match and the match to succeed. Instead of matching all the way to the end first.

Comment: @FarhadAliNoo it's a look-ahead. it will stop consuming input as soon as it matches, so in effect it's reluctant - it behaves like there's a `?` after the `.*` anyway

Answer (score 1):

Well you could have a `List<List<String>>` which you can compile into `List<Pattern>`:

```
for(List<String> terms : listOfTerms) {
    String pattern = StringUtils.join(terms, "|");
    patterns.add(Pattern.compile(pattern));
}
```

and then check:

```
for(Pattern p : patterns)
    if(!p.matches(string))
        return false;

return true;
```

This should make the checking easier. For defining the initial list of terms maybe Arrays would actually work better? Something like this:

`String[][] terms = {{"cat", "dog"}, {"a", "b"}...};`

Which could be formatted to look nice and could contain comments etc...